# UIAlertView delayed or not showing up when calling methods from another view

Tags: ios, objective-c, uialertview

UIAlertView delayed or not showing up when pass another view. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
-(void)viewDidLoad{
  levelContentController = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@""
                                                      message:@"Loading...
                                                     delegate:self
                                            cancelButtonTitle:nil
                                            otherButtonTitles:nil];
}
-(void)passToTestView:(id)sender{
[levelContentController show];
ViewController *viewController = [[ViewController alloc]init];
clickedLevelId = [[NSString alloc] init];
clickedLevelId = [testIdStringArray objectAtIndex:[sender tag]-1];
[viewController sendIndexMethod:sendIndex];
[viewController testCompletedArrayMethod:arrayOfCompletedTest];
[viewController parseTestURL:buttonTag getTestIdString:clickedLevelId];
viewController.viewSoundCheck = _levelSoundCheck;
[self presentViewController:viewController animated:YES completion:nil];

}

-(void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated{
    [levelContentController dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:0 animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: `UIAlertView` is deprecated as of iOS 9. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIAlertView_Class/ Intead, you should be using a `UIAlertController`. Here's a tutorial on it. http://useyourloaf.com/blog/uialertcontroller-changes-in-ios-8.html

Answer (score 2):

The above code has some problems.

When `passToTestView:` selector is called, it'll try to present the alertView. But within the same method you are trying to present another view controller.

This will in turn call `viewWillDisappear:` where you are hiding the alertView.

It's recommended that if you want to present the alertView while displaying `ViewController`, create and display `UIAlertView` instance in the `ViewController` class's `viewDidLoad` or `viewWillAppear:`. Do not initialise and display it in this viewController.

Answer (score 0):

To make the UIAlertView appear, you should call:

```
[contentLoadingController show];
```

Note that UIAlertView is deprecated in iOS9, and you should use UIAlertController.